# Why isn't my sIFR text wrapping on a liquid design?

Tags: text, word-wrap, sifr

I have a simple line of text I'm replacing with sIFR for a header on my site. The site is liquid so it scales when the browser window changes width. But when I shrink the browser window down, the alt text (when I turn it on for testing) wraps to another line, but the sIFR text doesn't.

I've seen written elsewhere on the web that people implement in the sifr.js code a `preventWrap=false` function, but being new to JavaScript I'm not sure where to put it to make it work.

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.sIFR-hasFlash h2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

And the relevant JavaScript:

```
 sIFR.replaceElement(named({sSelector: "h2", 
sFlashSrc: "flash/h2_font.swf", sBgColor: "#006633", 
sColor: "#FFFFFF", sFlashVars: "textalign=center", sWmode: "transparent"}));
```

Not sure where I would put the `preventWrap=false`, or if that's even the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

sIFR 3 should fix this.

Comment: Please include a link to and quote from the release notes?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, adding *position:relative* to your CSS might fix it.